# Is this proof that Cauchy sequences converge right?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to prove that a Cauchy sequence must converge. To do this I used the fact that a sequence converges if and only if its lim inf equals its lim sup, as follows:

> Consider a Cauchy sequence $\{a_n\}$, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb Z^+$ such that for all $m,n>N$, we have $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon$. We seek to show that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$.\begin{align*}
>     &-\epsilon<a_m-a_n<\epsilon\\
>     &\therefore -\epsilon+a_n<a_m<\epsilon+a_n\\
>     &\therefore -\epsilon+a_n\leq \liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m\leq a_m \leq \limsup_{m\to\infty}a_m\leq\epsilon+a_n\\
>     &\therefore |\liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m-a_n|\leq \epsilon \text{ and } |\limsup_{m\to\infty}a_m-a_n|\leq \epsilon\\
>     &\therefore |\liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m-a_n| + |a_n-\liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m|\leq 2\epsilon\\
>    & \therefore |\liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m-\limsup_{m\to\infty}a_m|\leq2\epsilon
> \end{align*}
> Hence we conclude $\liminf_{m\to\infty}a_n=\limsup_{m\to\infty}a_n$, and therefore by part (a) every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converges.

Is my proof correct? The other proofs I read of this all seem much longer, including another one on this website which also uses lim inf = lim sup.

Comment: How do you get $a_m\le\limsup_{m\to\infty}a_m$?

Comment: I think that's where my mistake is. $\sup a_m$ is by definition an upper bound, but $\limsup_{m\to\infty} a_m$ need not be. Thank you!